# Upconversion Particles in Biological Tissues

Tags: optics, visible-light, scattering, biophysics, absorption

So I was learning about upconversion particles in biological tissues and understand mainly how they work. UV-Vis light are scattered and absorbed by tissues, so we instead send near-infrared light to the tissues, which hits the particles deep in the tissues. Then the particles upconvert and send UV-vis light emission that is detected by a machine.

My main question is, when the UV-vis light is emitted from the upconversion, wouldn't this emission also be scattered and absorbed by the tissues? How come scattering and absorption is not a problem with the UV-vis light emission from upconverting particles deep in the tissues?

I would greatly appreciate any help on this response.

Answer (score 1):

I can imagine this as a treatment technique. If the particles are absorbed by a tumor, UV-vis light originates in the tumor and illuminates mostly the tumor. This might be intended to kill the tumor.

Imaging might be a secondary concern. You would learn the position and size of the tumor by light any attenuated and scattered light that makes it to the surface.

If imaging is the primary purpose, absorption and scattering is less in a one way trip through the tissue and it would be if illuminated from the outside.

Comment: Thank you for your input! Just wondering, wouldn't the resolution of the image be poor still for imaging when it tries to exit out of the tissue and encounters scattering and absorption? Assuming the primary purpose is only imaging.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upconverting_nanoparticles#Applications has more on this. One problem with tumors is they look just like other tissue. One way to identify them is to administer a chemical that is attracted to the tumor, and then find the chemical. PET scans do this with radioactive tracers, which have obvious drawbacks.